# Are there leaderboards/tables/stats that compare inference times between close-sourced LLMs such as GPT 3.5/4 and Claude?

Tags: reference-request, comparison, gpt, inference, claude

https://huggingface.co/spaces/optimum/llm-perf-leaderboard is great to compare inference times between LLMs but it misses close-sourced LLMs such as GPT 3.5/4 and Claude.